# Use Mock HTTP with Protractor and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

How can I use Mock HTTP with Jasmine and Protractor ?

In my **test.spec.js**, I declared a mock, but this mock doesn't work. I don't have any error. My api always responds and not the mock.

I never see 'mockModule!' in my console.
My function is never executed :

```
browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {

    browser.executeScript(function() {console.log('mockModule!')});

    angular.module('modName', []).value('foo', 'bar').run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('http://api.webapp.net/app_dev.php/module/search?direction=asc&page=1').respond('repsond');

    browser.executeScript(function() {console.log('enter mockModule!')});
    });
});
```

In my app.js I don't have "ngMock".

I added this in my index.html :

```
node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
```

I run the test from the command prompt with 'gulp protractor-local':

```
gulp.task('protractor-local', shell.task([
        'protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl="http://mywebapp.local.net"'
]));
```

All tests are ok, but not the mock.

**test.spec.js**

```
var loginPO = new(require('./models/login.model.js'))();

describe("hello", function() {

    it("I click on the button-search button", function() {

        loginPO.wait(10);

        //browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

        browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {

            browser.executeScript(function() {console.log('mockModule!')});

            angular.module('modName', []).value('foo', 'bar').run(function ($httpBackend) {
                $httpBackend.whenPOST('http://api.webapp.net/app_dev.php/module/search?direction=asc&page=1').respond('repsond');

                browser.executeScript(function() {console.log('enter mockModule!')});
            });
        });

        //browser.getRegisteredMockModules();

        loginPO.clickButtonSearchButton();
        loginPO.wait(10);
    });

    it("I am on the home page", function() {
        loginPO.visit('#/');
    });

    ...

});
```

**models/login.model.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

var LoginPageObject = function() {

    var signInButton = element(by.id('signIn'));

    _.mixin(this, require('./common/base.js').Base);

    this.path = '#/';

    this.clickButtonSearchButton = function() {
        return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('button-search')).click();
    };

    ...

};

module.exports = LoginPageObject;
```

**common/base.js**

```
function visit(path, params) {
    return browser.get(this.path + (params || ''));
}

function wait(params) {
    params = params * 1000;
    return browser.sleep(params);
}
...

exports.Base = {
    visit: visit,
    wait: wait,
    ...
};
```

**protractor.config.js**

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar',

  specs: [
    'jasmine/*.spec.js'
  ],

  getPageTimeout: 30000,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    version: '',
    platform: 'ANY'
  },

  framework: 'jasmine2'

};
```

** karma.conf.js **

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {

    var configuration = {

        basePath: './',

        frameworks: [
            'jasmine-jquery',
            'jasmine',
            'jasmine-matchers'
        ],

        files: [
            ...
            'assets/libs/angularjs/angular.min.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            ...
            'assets/libs/angularjs/sweetalert.min.js',
            'assets/libs/angularjs/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
            'app/app.js',
            'app/*/*.js',
            'app/*/*/*.js',
            'app/*/*/*/*.js',
            {
                pattern: 'app/*/*/*/*/*.json',
                included: false
            }
        ],

        exclude: [],

        preprocessors: {
            'app/**/!(*.test).js': ['coverage']
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'text',
            dir: 'coverage/'
        },

        reporters: ['spec'],

        port: 8080,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        singleRun: true,

        customLaunchers: {
            'PhantomJS_custom': {
                base: 'PhantomJS',
                    options: {
                        windowName: 'my-window',
                        settings: {
                        webSecurityEnabled: false
                    }
                },
                flags: ['--load-images=true'],
                debug: true
            }
        },

        phantomjsLauncher: {
            exitOnResourceError: true
        }
    };

    config.set(configuration);
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.5",
    "chromedriver": "^2.19.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.0",
    ...
    "protractor": "^2.5.1",
    "selenium-server": "^2.48.2",
    "selenium-standalone": "^4.7.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.48.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: are you running from browser or command prompt?

Comment: I run the test from the command prompt with : 

protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl="http://mywebapp.local.net"

Comment: Also please share KARMA config file

Comment: Karma run phamtomjs and execute my unit tests.

Comment: one more why you need ngMock with protractor?We use ngMock for unit testing with jasmine or other and protractor is E2E testing framework. no need of ngMock with protractor

Comment: okay, I removed this line in my index.html "<script src="node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>". My mock doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `protractor-http-mock`?

Comment: no because after I would like to use cucumber.js

Comment: you are mixing protractor and jasmine unit testing

Comment: I added my code: my function "browser.addMockModule(...)" doesn't execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem, and I resolved it creating a wrapper module with all mocks

```
  angular.module('mockBackend', ['myAppModule', 'ngMockE2E']).run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', /user/).respond(200, {login: 'user_test'});
  });
```

And change the directive data-ng-app in the index file to mockBackend module

```
<html data-ng-app='mockBackend'>
```

You can configure a gulp/grunt task to include this module and change the data-ng-app before run your tests.

In this link you can see a complete example: http://blog.xebia.com/angularjs-e2e-testing-using-ngmocke2e/

Comment: Good idea ! Have you loaded the json file in response in httpbackend ?

Comment: I haven't, but it sounds very elegant!

Comment: To load JSON file from httpbackend, It works with this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24287558/5453732

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are mixing E2E testing and jasmine unit testing.
For E2E testing using protractor.

Also make sure you have included your test file path in karma config for jasmine unit testing.

Make sure `Selenium  webdriver-manager` is uptodate

e.g.

Snippet html for login page.

```
<div class="form-group" 
             ng-class=" {'has-error' :!loginForm.userEmail.$pristine && loginForm.userEmail.$invalid}" >
            <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
            <input  type="email" name="userEmail"   class="form-control" required  placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="objUser.userEmail">        
            <div ng-show="loginForm.userEmail.$touched || loginForm.$submitted">
                <span ng-show="loginForm.userEmail.$error.required">Please enter valid email</span>
                <span ng-show="loginForm.userEmail.$error.email">Please enter valid email</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Protractor js for this html

```
describe("check user creation form integration", function() {

    var ptor,userEmail,userPassword;
    beforeEach(function(){
        ptor = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        userEmail       = element(by.model("objUser.userEmail"));
    });

    it("\n\n1 . check login functionality",function(){

        browser.get("/#/");
        userEmail.sendKeys("*^*");
        expect(userEmail.getAttribute("class")).toContain('ng-invalid');
         userEmail.clear();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        userEmail.sendKeys("HJJHJH");
        expect(userEmail.getAttribute("class")).toContain('ng-valid');
    })
});
```

**protractor config**

add following line

```
exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

port will be change as per your config.

Comment: I don't understand. I Use karma+jasmine to run my unit tests (with "karma start", and I use protractor+jasmine to run my end to end tests (with "protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl="mywebapp.local.net""). For me there is no bridge between karma and protractor.

Comment: for protractor E2E testing there is no need to run karma.You can run by protractor command

Comment: yes I know, I don't run karma with protractor, only protractor